# How do i edit the links in the top nav bar on an enterprise wiki site?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, top-link-bar, enterprise-wiki

I would like to edit and change the links in the top nav bar on my enterprise wiki.

Currently the links are "About this wiki" and "Recent" a drop down menu with links.

I would like to change "About this wiki" to a "Home" page link and remove the "Recent" drop down menu and links. I also would like to be able to add more links to the to the top nav bar.

I there anyway I can do this one an enterprise wiki site?

Thanks

zingwing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site settings / Look and Feel / Navigation. Check Global Navigation and structural navigation

Comment: I already have it enabled, but i've read since it's a publishing site (enterprise wiki) I don't have the button for "Edit Link". So im not sure how I can customize the links.

Comment: Oh I think I found what you are talking about

Comment: Sweet thanks, i've been looking for this for awhile.